# Domain satisfying cone condition

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations

I first give a definition

Let $\nu$ be a non-zero vector in $\mathbb R^2$, and for each $x\neq 0$ let $\angle(x,\nu)$ be the angle between the position vector $x$ and $\nu$. For given such $\nu, \kappa$ satisfying $0\leq\kappa\leq\pi$, the set
$$C=\{x\in\mathbb R^2: x=0,\angle(x,\nu)\leq \kappa/2 \}$$
is called a finite cone with axis direction $\nu$ and aperture angle $\kappa$ with vertex at the origin. Note that $x+C=\{x+y: y\in C\}$ is a finite cone with vertex at $x$ but the same dimensions and axis direction as $C$ and is obtained by parallel translation of $C$.

And the question is: Let $\Omega \in\mathbb R^2$ be unbounded domain but satifying bounded in one direction. So does $\Omega$ satisfy cone condition, and does $\mathbb R^2\setminus \bar{\Omega}$ contain semi-cone?

Thanks for answering so much!

Comment: 1. Are we to forget the standard cone condition? 2. By your definition $C=\{0\}$, which looks a typo. 3. Are rotations to be excluded in your cone condition? 4. What is semi-cone? 5. Is "being bounded in one direction" the only restriction on $\Omega$?

Comment: 1. I look this definition in book: "Sobolev spaces - R.A.Adam". 2. I also don't know semi-cone, so shy. 3. $\Omega$ is only bounded in one direction.

Comment: You don't give a definition of the cone condition. What you give is just a definition of a finite cone from page 81 of "Sobolev spaces" by Adams-Fournier spoiled by mistakes (height $\rho$ missing). Definition of the cone condition is on page 82. After you read it, you will see that before any restrictions are imposed on the boundary $\partial\Omega$ (smoothness or geometry) your question makes no sense -- there is nothing to check.

Comment: I really don't know semi-cone (although i searched in many books and google), so i can't give any conclusion whether $\mathbb R^2\setminus\bar{\Omega}$ contains semi-cone. Maybe semi-cone apply to $\angle(x,\nu)<\kappa/4$. If so we have $\Omega$ satisfies cone condition and $\mathbb R^2\setminus\bar{\Omega}$ contains semi-cone. I guess that!

Comment: That guess seems doubtful. A one-and-the-same corner point at $\partial\Omega$ of the aperture $\alpha$ from inside $\Omega$ will be of the aperture $2\pi-\alpha$ from outside. What is the exact formulation of your problem?

Comment: My problem: Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ be bounded in one direction with smooth boundary. So $\Omega$ satisfies cone condition and $\mathbb R^2\setminus \bar{\Omega}$ contains semi-cone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is still underdetermined with its context staying unclear. *Smooth boundary* of unspecified smoothness usually implies a *sufficiently smooth boundary* when the context is clear, and not worse than Lipschitz in any case.   A domain $\Omega$ is said to satisfy the cone condition if there is a finite cone $C$ of height $\rho$ and aperture $\kappa$ such that each $x\in\Omega$ is the vertex of some cone $C_x\subset\Omega$ congruent to $C$. Of course, an unbounded domain $\Omega$ bounded in one direction will satisfy the cone condition with some cone $C$ for sufficiently small $\rho$ and $\kappa$ in case $\partial\Omega$ is uniformly smooth. And of course, an open set $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\overline{\Omega}$ will satisfy the cone condition with some cone $\widetilde{C}$. Can $\widetilde{C}$ be chosen as a *semi-cone* with respect to $C$? Not necessarily, if a semi-cone is to be understood directly as a finite cone of height $\rho/2$ and aperture $\kappa/2$.   Indeed, a boundary $\partial\Omega$ may possess, say, certain narrow windings impenetrable for a cone $\widetilde{C}_x\,$. But the cone $C$ could as well be chosen with $\rho$ and $\kappa$ small enough for $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\overline{\Omega}$ to fit the cone condition with the semi-cone 
$\widetilde{C}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help and details of answer! Look forward to seeing your answer in my next questions.

Comment: I have a new question and i really need your help. Can you give me your email so that i will send my question to you?

Comment: email address:"mkl314@mail.ru"